# simple question about apache serv in linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

i installed the apache, php and mysql. It is initialized and works in the browser - simple file with "it works!".

But now, where is the folder www? i can't find it.

Comment: Which Linux distro?

Comment: it is a distro based in mandriva (caixa magica 15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will vary depending on the linux distro you are using, a few common places:

- /var/www
- /usr/local/apache/htdoc

Comment: perfect. thanks!! - (7 minutes to accept)

Answer (score 0):

There is no common answer for all Linux distributions out there (yet). The usual approach is to check the docs. But where are they?

My approach for problems like that is to list the installed files. For RedHat based systems, try `rpm -ql apache`. For Debian based ones, use `dpkg -L apache`.

That shows you all the files which belong to the package `apache` which should give you an idea where the files are which the server serves you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/etc/apache2`, and then `grep -ri DocumentRoot *`, which is likely to output the directory you are looking for.

(This is assuming you installed Apache 2. For apache 1.x, go to /etc/apache instead.)

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/apache/htdoc is common.  But check your docs.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/tutorials.html

This link tells you how to find your root doc. - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-unix-linux-apache-documentroot/